# Can we switch front and rear camera using Twilio Javascript Client in Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, mobile, twilio

I am developing web and Cordova application video call functionality using Twilio Client, I want to toggle rear and front camera on mobile device. Twilio provides access of only front camera, is there a way to switch between front and rear camera(basically a toggle functionality  using Twilio library)

Comment: Have you been able to get this to work on iOS?

Answer (score 2):

The Twilio-Video JS library does have support for doing this.

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
const { connect, createLocalTracks } = Twilio.Video;

navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(devices => {
  var videoInput = devices.find(device => device.kind === 'videoinput');
  return createLocalTracks({ audio: true, video: { deviceId: videoInput.deviceId } });
}).then(localTracks => {
  return connect('my-token', { name: 'my-room-name', tracks: localTracks });
}).then(room => {
  console.log('Connected to room ' + room.name);
});
```

Comment: Tried your code but it doesn't work. No matter what deviceId I give the createLocalTracks() function, even a bogus one, it still returns a video track if there is one without matching. Also the documentation doesn't show that this is even an option. They show a 'name' property in the docs but no deviceId can be given. I think it ignores it. See: https://sdk.twilio.com/js/video/releases/2.0.0-beta16/docs/global.html#CreateLocalTrackOptions